# ReactJS: Give Function Simultaneous Access to Parent and Child Props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

I am working on a project in ReactJS where I where I would like a parent class to be able to pass an onClick event to one of its child components in the render() function, and have that onClick event be able to access the props of both the parent and child.

I have figured out how to have the function access the parent and child separately, but not simultaneously.

For parent I use:

```
//in parent class
clickHandler(){
    //do something with this.props.etc 
}
render(){
<myChild onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}/>
}
```

For child I use:

```
//In parent class
clickHandler(status, content, e){
    //do something with button status and content passed from child props 
}
render(){
return <myChild onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}/>;
}

//in child class
render{
const { onClick } = this.props;
const { status } = this.state;
return <button onClick={(e) => onClick(status, this.props.content, e)}>click me</button>;
}
```

How can I combine the two to in order to get simultaneous access to both parent and child props?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "simultaneously" but child cannot access parent props. Your example is confusing (you have 2 parent examples) and I'm not sure what your expected behavior is...

Comment: The child never accesses the parent props. I am creating a function in the parent class for onClick which is passed to the child. I would like this function to have access to both parent and child props.

Comment: I do not have 2 parent examples. In the first example the function (clickHandler) has access to the parent props. In the second example the function can get access to the child's props in the form of function arguments. The idea is to be able to achieve both of these at the sample time, so that the function can receive props from the child as arguments and do something with the props of the parent.

Comment: You have `"in parent class"` in two places and 3 render functions and empty handlers, so it's just not clear to me what you're trying to do. Try to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

I think *maybe* you are over thinking it - React is just javascript at the end of the day, therefore, you can so something like:

```
// In parent class
clickHandler(status, content, e) {
    // status, content are the props passed up from the child
    console.log(status);
    console.log(content);

    // "this" still refers to parent class, so...
    // a, b, c are from the parent props 
    const { a, b, c } = this.props;

}

render(){
    return <myChild onClick={this.clickHandler.bind(this)}/>;
}

// In child class
render {
    const { onClick } = this.props;
    const { status } = this.state;
    return <button onClick={(e) => onClick(status, this.props.content, e)}>click me</button>;
}
```